# How to correct '' PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to ''

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to call a function(`ADD_PRICELIST`) that gets values in this one:

*the add_pricelist function complied successfully.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PRICELIST_DATA(
  CPRIC_DATA_ID CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMERS_ID%TYPE,
  IPRIC_DATA_ID ITEMS.ITEMS_ID%TYPE
)
RETURN NUMBER AS
  L_PRICELIST_DATA_ID NUMBER;
BEGIN
        L_PRICELIST_DATA_ID := ADD_PRICELIST(ROUND(dbms_random.value(0,10),3)); 
      END IF;
  RETURN L_PRICELIST_DATA_ID;    
END PRICELIST_DATA;
```

Gives me:

```
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to ADD_PRICELIST
```

Comment: how are you calling the function ?

Comment: How is the `MINI_ERP.ADD_PRICELIST` function defined - does it expect a single number argument (and return a number)? Please edit your question to at least show the specification for that function.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with the `CREATE PACKAGE` or `CREATE FUNCTION` statement where `MINI_ERP.ADD_PRICELIST` is defined.

Comment: Well, the function expects three arguments, and you only supply one. (It also always returns null, as you never set `ADD_PLIST_ID`.) Is your random value supposed to be the price? I don't really understand your looping or logic...

Comment: Why is `ADD_PRICELIST` a function and not a procedure? Functions typically do not have side-effects and have a meaningful return value. Your "function" does have side-effects as it inserts into the table and the return value is never set so will always be `NULL`; that is more like the behaviour of a procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ADD_PRICELIST` function as the signature:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ADD_PRICELIST(
  L_PLIST_CUST_ID CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMERS_ID%TYPE,
  L_PLIST_ITEMS_ID ITEMS.ITEMS_ID%TYPE,
  P_PRICELIST_PRICE NUMBER
) RETURN NUMBER
```

This takes 3 values and returns 1 value (which, as an aside, will always return `NULL`).

You are only calling it with a single argument:

```sql
L_PRICELIST_DATA_ID := MINI_ERP.ADD_PRICELIST(
  ROUND(dbms_random.value(0,10),3)
);
```

Which gives you the error:

```sql
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to ADD_PRICELIST
```

To solve this, you need to pass the other 2 arguments so that the function has all 3 expected arguments.

For example:

```sql
L_PRICELIST_DATA_ID := MINI_ERP.ADD_PRICELIST(
  ROUND(dbms_random.value(0,10),3),
  ROUND(dbms_random.value(0,10),3),
  ROUND(dbms_random.value(0,10),3)
);
```